# Efficiency of using AlarmManager to update App Widgets in Android

Tags: android, widget

I have developed an App Widget that requires to be updated every 10 minutes. In Android documentation about App Widgets it is specified that if the widget needs to be updated more frequently than once per hour, it is recommended to use AlarmManager and set the alarm type to either RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME so the alarm is only delivered when the device is awake.

I have implemented the AlarmManager and my widget is updating correctly every 10 minutes. After several testings, using both RTC and ELAPSED_REALTIME alarm types, I have seen that my widget is still getting updated after the device goes to sleep. I can see in LogCat that my widget is getting updated even after 30 minutes that the device went to sleep (30 minutes after the screen turns off).

My question is, if the alarm is still been delivered and my widget is updated every 10 minutes even after the device has gone to sleep how is using AlarmManager with RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME as the documentation says more battery efficient than just setting 600,000 milliseconds for updatePeriodMillis property on my widget provider xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Both RTC and ELAPSE_REAL_TIME have WAKEUP and non WAKEUP versions, so if you do not want you widget updating when the phone is sleeping, you could chose the non WAKEUP version. If you set `updatePeriodMillis`, it is going to wake the device either way.
2. When you set your alarm using  `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()`, Android will bundle multiple inexact alarms and fire them at the same time, which is more battery efficient. Also according to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

   > As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.
3. Another thing is that, according to the [AppWidgetProviderInfo doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis):

   > Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more
   >   than once every 30 minutes.

so it probably wouldn't be useful to you if you needed to update every 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the non wakeup version of RTC which is `AlarmManager.RTC` and I know that as of API 19 all alarms are inexact, so how will using setInexactRepeating make any difference? Thanks for clarifying the updatePeriodMillis property for me.

Comment: @Israel After API 19 it doesn't really matter what you are using since the alarm is inexact either way. But the thing is that inexact alarms are less battery draining since they are all bundled together instead of firing one by one in close intervals. I could not find anything in the doc, but it might be the case that they suggest Alarms instead of updatePeriodMillis, cause updatePeriodMillis might be exact.

Comment: @Israel Also, another reason `updatePeriodMillis` is less battery efficient is that it is going to wake up the device no matter what (updated answer).

Comment: I understand, I will use `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()` which will make my widget a little more battery efficient. But the question still lies on the table...why is Android still firing the alarm every 10 minutes if I'm using the non wake up version of RTC (`AlarmManager.RTC`) even when the device is sleeping?

Comment: @Israel Is this behavior repeating? Could it be possible that the phone was woken up by some other app at this point so your alarm triggered? Are you able to reproduce it consistently?

Comment: Yes, I tested in 4 different devices, Nexus 4 with LOLLIPOP_MR1 (Android 5.1), Samsung Galaxy S3 with JELLY_BEAN_MR2 (Android 4.3), Samsung Galaxy S4 with KITKAT (Android 4.4.2) and an Alcatel OneTouch POP C1 with JELLY_BEAN_MR1 (Android 4.2.2). In all of them, the widget has still being updated after the screen went off. Maybe the reason is another app waking up the phone as you said and causing my alarm to fire, but I don't know how can I test this scenario.